# Configure Twitter app in rails for multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make a twitter Application in rails and configure it for multiple users. But I'm unsure what I have to do in the configuration. My configuration code in twitter controller is

```
Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
config.consumer_key = 'xxxxxxx'
config.consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxx'
config.oauth_token = 'xxxxxx'
config.oauth_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxx'
end
```

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried?

Comment: I want to add twitter API in my project & i want that my every client will enter their twitter account details .After that  twitter api will authenticate  client  & after that it will be redirected to twitter profile page where it will display  user timeline(it will display tweets which user posted) & home timeline (it will display all tweets including tweets of person user following)

Comment: i did all these things but i am facing one problem that i created twitter handle from my account  because of this reason it will display timeline of my account even if i am signed in from different account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two values `consumer_key`and `consumer_secret` are app-specific, which you need to use throughout your entire app.

On the other hand `oauth_token`and `oauth_token_secret` are user-specific, meaning that you feed them with the oauth token the current user returns (and *not* your personal oauth token).

You can find more information at [Twitter Developers: Obtaining access tokens](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview).

Comment: How i will retrieve oauth_token & oauth_token_secret....should i provide it directly in my code or i have to  write code to retrieve these values from app

Comment: If you want your app to do something on behalf of a specific user, the app will need to use the credentials of that user to connect to the API. Most likely you will want to use the [3-legged authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged). You cannot save the token in your code, as each user has a different token.

Comment: i totally agree with  you that i have to use 3-legged authorization but i am not getting the value of access token.If you want i can share my  twitter controller code with you

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean with "i am not getting the value of access token"? Have you already implemented 3-legged auth and are looking for a bug in your code, or are you looking for information on how to implement it? Or something else? Please post all relevant code. And if your question deviates from your original question, I suggest opening a new question (and marking this one as closed).

Comment: I already implemented 3-legged aut,Error of access-token is also resolved But now i am facing new error  i am getting timeline of  account from which i created twitter api even  i am logged in from different account.Here is the link of gem which i used  http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-social-gems-twitter/

Comment: You will always get the timeline for the user account of which you're using the oauth token. You will need to create a seperate api connection for each user, using their oauth tokens instead of the one you generated initially. You might be ble to find out what's going on if you add some debug code around api connections to check the Twitter::User. If you find out that it's the wrong user, you will need to find out where you're using the wrong connection data.

Comment: @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key = ''
    config.consumer_secret = ''
    config.access_token= ''
    config.access_token_secret= ''
    end

Comment: I write this code in config/intializer/twitter.rb & in controller i am calling it by   def twitter_profile
         user_timeline = client.user_timeline
         home_timeline = client.home_timeline
      end

Comment: Please re-read my initial answer. You may not define oauth_token and oauth_token_secret statically, as it is user dependent. Also, please post a new question with the *entire code* you're using that's related to twitter, and mark this question as answered. Unless you consider your original question not answered yet.

Comment: Okay maia i am posting my new question  with code & i will comment link of that question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350866/configure-twitter-api-for-multiple-users

Comment: In the code I've briefly seen you always use @client with the same token (your own token). Did you check newer documentations of the twitter gem yet? (your tutorial is from 2012 and might be out of date)

Comment: can i implement pagination on twitter timeline of my rails project

Comment: How does this question relate to your original question how to configure a rails app to use the twitter gem?

Comment: Actually maia my problem is resolved now ........i am working on pagination in twitter rails app

Comment: If your problem is resolved (btw, what was the solution?) and you have a different question, please submit it as new question (after making sure it's not a duplicate).